# Problems with a fibonacci's series calculator

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){

    int N,  k, l, F0,serial_position_of_N,num_of_seqs_tested,sign;

    printf("please insert a number:\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%u", &N);

    //if N=0
    if( N == 0 ){
        printf("%d is the %dth item of the sequence F1 = F0 = %d.\n
            %d sequences were checked.\n", 0, 2, 0, 1);
            return 0;
    }

    //checks if N is odd or even
    if( N % 2 == 0 ){
        printf("N is and even number....\n\n");
        fflush(stdout);

      //if N is even
      for( F0 = 1; F0 + F0 > fabs( N ); ++F0, ++num_of_seqs_tested ){
          int pos;

          if( fabs( N ) == F0 ){
              pos = 2;
              break;
          }

          for( k = F0, l = F0, pos = 2; k+l > fabs( N ); k = l, l = k + l, pos++ ){
              if(k+l == fabs(N)){
          pos++;
          sign = 1;
          break;
          }
      }

      if( sign == 1 ){
          serial_position_of_N = pos;
          break;
      }
    }

    //if N is Odd
    else{
        printf( "N is and odd number....\n\n" );
        fflush( stdout );
        for( F0 = 1; F0 + F0 > fabs( N ); F0= F0 + 2, ++num_of_seqs_tested){
            int pos;

        if( fabs( N ) == F0 ){
            pos = 2;
            break;
        }

        for( k = F0, l = F0, pos = 2; k+l>fabs(N); k = l, l = k+l, pos++ ){

            if( k + l == fabs( N ) ){
                pos++;
                break;
            }

        }


        if( k+l == fabs( N ) ){
            serial_position_of_N = pos;
            break;
            }
        }
    }

//if N is negetive
    if( N < 0 ){
        printf("%d is the %dth item of the sequence F1 = F0 = %d.\n%d sequences were checked.\n", N, serial_position_of_N, (-1)*F0, num_of_seqs_tested);
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    //other
    printf( "%d is the %dth item of the sequence F1 = F0 = %d.\n%d sequences were checked.\n", N, serial_position_of_N, F0, num_of_seqs_tested );
    fflush(stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

=========================================

This code is for a Fibonacci - to check for which Fibonacci sequence the Nth number belong to.

Needless to say I have problem - I put 8 as input and this is the ouptut:

8 is the 4201440th item of the sequence F1 = F0 = 1.
4201534 sequences were checked.

BTW - I run windows 7 64 bit on my laptop pc, and run the eclipse c/c++

Comment: sorry for the bad code orginizing. i thought <i> and </i> is for that??

Comment: You have a plus } after the second comparison

Answer (score 1):

You don't initialise your variables, in particular `num_of_seqs_tested` and `serial_position_of_N` are used without being initialised.

```
scanf("%u", &N);
```

is incorrect, since `N` is a signed `int` (it will still work if you input non-negative numbers `<= INT_MAX`, probably). If you enter 8, you will execute the code path

```
if( N % 2 == 0 ){
    printf("N is and even number....\n\n");
    fflush(stdout);

  //if N is even
  for( F0 = 1; F0 + F0 > fabs( N ); ++F0, ++num_of_seqs_tested ){
```

and since `1 + 1 < 8`, the loop will never run. You probably meant to use `<` instead of `>`.

Note, however, that

```
for( k = F0, l = F0, pos = 2; k+l > fabs( N ); k = l, l = k + l, pos++ ){
```

doesn't produce anything resembling the Fibonacci sequence, after the first update in the loop, you will have the invariant `l = 2*k` (until `l` overflows).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is confusing, try to make it simpler. Another thing in your *for*, you have the following condition `F0+F0>fabs(N)` this means that you are calculating for each *for* iteration `fab(N)`, which is highly inefficient/redundant. Just make `int x = fab(N)` before the loop, and put on the loop condition `F0+F0 > x`, the same can be applied to `F0+F0.`

It would be better if the `fibonacci` function received the `N`, calculated the Fibonacci and verified (at the same time) if the actual term is equal to your value. Something like this:

```
int fibonacci(int n)
{
  int a = 0,b = 1, sum;
  int n_th = 1;
  int find = 0;
  int erro = 0; 
  while(!find && !erro)         // Search until it is find or a erro occurs.
  {
    if(a == n) find = 1;           // we find it;
    else if ( a > n) erro = 1;     // this means that N do not belong to fibonacci
    else n_th++;                   // increment the position of the term
    sum = a + b;                   // sum = the previous 2 terms
    a = b;                         // a takes the value of the actual term
    b = sum;                       // b becomes the next term
  }
  if(erro) return 0;               // Means that N do not belong to fibonacci.
  else return n_th;                // Gives the position.
}
```